# How to replace the Top Link Bar with promoted Links on SharePoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, navigationbar

Can someone point me to the right direction. I want to replace the Top Navigation bar on SharePoint 2013 with a promoted link menu. is this possible? i know i will have to use either SharePoint designer or Visual Studio for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. I have managed to modify the top global navigation through Site Settings > Navigation.

I've chosen Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site (for the global nav) - Show subsites > and then hidden those I didn't want to display, and added in (via "Add Link") any of those promoted links that I did want.

Once you've got the items you want appearing, then you can style it however you want through CSS.

If you want dynamic promoted links, then that is much more complicated and outside of my knowledge base :)

Hope that helps!